# Solr 4.6 admin "Loading" after initial installation never completes

Tags: tomcat, solr

I've just installed the TomCat 7.0.50 and Solr 4.6 on a Windows 2008R2 server.
When I try to access solr from the local machine

```
 (http://localhost:8080/solr)
```

I get the left half of the page (looks like nav menu) and the right half I see the "Loading" with the spinner.

I've only brought the default configuration from the example folder (collection1) into this solr core.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, 
Sid

BTW I have a solr 3.6 running fine on another server which works fine

Comment: what browser are you using? If it is IE, what version, can you test with chrome/ff? What browser are you using to access solr3.6 in the other server?

Comment: I can confirm that IE8 and downwards will not work with Solr's admin web application. We had that issue. Use FireFox or Chrome instead.